# Micrometer timer/histogram control buckets

Tags: prometheus, servlet-filters, micrometer

We are using Micrometer in our **non** **sprint-boot** app and our target monitoring system in Prometheus. We created a filter for calibrating response times.

Sample code for timer looks like this in servlet filter:

```
Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start(prometheusRegistry);
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    String host = servletRequest.getServerName();
    String path = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
    String method = servletRequest.getMethod();
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        sample.stop(Timer.builder(METRIC_NAME)
                .description(METRIC_HELP)
                .tags(HOST, host)
                .tags(PATH, path)
                .tags(METHOD, method)
                .tags(STATUS, Integer.toString(servletResponse.getStatus()))
                .publishPercentileHistogram(true) //create histogram, not summary
                .minimumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMillis(10))
                .maximumExpectedValue(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .register(prometheusRegistry);
    }
```

As of now it is generating some 55 buckets for the min and max expected values that i added. I am primarily using publishPercentileHistogram(true) so that buckets can be aggregated across dimensions (like pods or instances). Is there a way to control the number of buckets but still possible to aggregate across the dimensions?

Does mentioning only serviceLevelObjectives() without publishPercentileHistogram() allows aggregation on prometheus side?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want more, less or explicitly define buckets?
Right now the only way is SLOs, you should add all the buckets you want using it.

Comment: Thanks. Does this allow me to aggregate them across dimension on server side (at prometheus)?

Comment: Yes, they are basically the same but based on these questions, I would recommend using the default bucketing strategy of Micrometer instead of defining your own custom one.